# Check 2 conditions using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to have 2 conditions in this case? I want to check e-mail too not only the username.

```php
$checkuser = htmlentities($_POST["username"]);
$data = $connect_pdo->prepare('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?');
$data->bindParam(1, $checkuser);
$data->execute();
if ($data->rowCount() > 0) {
    $linha = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    //user already exists
} else {
    //execute query
}
```

I need to check e-mail too, not only username, so there would be 2 conditions in the script. Can someone help?

Also, I would like to check them separately, so I could set the messages based on email or user, like *"user already exists"* or *"email already exists"* and (if not) then run the execute.

Comment: `WHERE username = ? or email = ?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check the `fetch()`, which is a better alternative than using `rowCount()` (as this method may not always be reliable in all databases). Also keep in mind that `htmlentities()` can alter the data, so this should never be used on input (like queries to the database), only output (when printing data on the website).

You can add a `OR email = ?` condition, and bind that separately.

If you want to check if one or both of the values exist, you can loop through the result-set and set a value if the value used in the query matches the value from the database. Then you can print them accordingly.

```php
$matches_found = [];

$data = $connect_pdo->prepare('SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?');
$data->execute([$_POST["username"], $_POST["email"]]);

if ($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    do {
        if ($row->username == $_POST['username']) {
            $matches_found['username_exists'] = 'username';
        }
        if ($row->email == $_POST['email']) {
            $matches_found['email_exists'] = 'email';
        }
    } while ($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

    echo "The ".implode(" and ", $matches_found)." already exists.";
} else {
    //execute query
}
```

Note that this can be prone to race-conditions - where the first query returns 0 results, but the data gets inserted to the database in the very short window of time before the insertion query happens.

Comment: is there anyway to use them separately, so I could set the messages based on email or user, like `user already exists` `email already exists` and then run the query?

Comment: Yes, see the above. You can either print the `$matches_found` values separately, or you can implode them together like shown (this will either be `The username already exists` or `The username and email already exists`.

Comment: can I add a `var` to `$matches_found['email_exists']` ? because I use a `$lang['array']` to show the message in different languages

Comment: Yes, of course. My answer shows you how the logic behind it can be done - if you want to alter the messages, you can do that as you need it to.

Comment: Ok I will mark as right but I did't tested yet, I will test latter, thank you!